# I need to add two signals having different frequencies

Tags: mosfet, rf, power-electronics, square

For my work I need to add OUTPUT from a PWM controlled Mosfet, with the current passing through the motor. I looking for some circuit to do this operation, I don't know how to proceed. Can you guys suggest me some ideas to proceed further.

The shape of the curve from the motor is sinusoidal and output from mosfet is square.

I need a electronic circuit to do the operation.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Assume you've managed to add the two signals; what are you going to do with the result?

Comment: @Narendra it might be better to provide a schematic to provide some context, its a little unclear as to what you mean by output on mosfet since all mosfets have an output. Your input voltage also needs to be factored in and the mosfet part itself. If your looking for a circuit did you try google? https://www.google.com/search?q=mosfet+switch+motor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 If you want some help please use the circuit tool and draw a circuit be more specific and actually ask a question. Then get your question re opened. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As your question is written, you are trying to do something that is not possible. The output of a PWM is a ratio. The current through a motor is a current. You cannot meaningfully add a ratio and a current, as they are different dimensions. It's like trying to add 2 metres to 1kg.

The only way that what you are trying to do could make sense is if you wanted to add two things of the same dimension. Your title suggests that the frequency of each signal could be that compatible dimension, though that's not clear. It may be that you are trying to add the PWM ratio (a number) to the number of amps flowing through the motor (a number). It may be that you are trying to add the average current, or even the instantaneous current from a PWM controlled FET, to the motor current.

Do not confuse the physical representation of a signal with what that signal means. A signal representing the number '2.03' for instance can have many different forms. With suitable scaling it could be 2.03V, a PWM ratio of 0.203, a PWM frequency of 20.3kHz, a floating point IEEE754 number 2.03 in the register of an MCU.

Once you have specified exactly what you are trying to do, then the process is as follows:

a) convert both signals into a compatible form, so demodulate frequency (in Hz) to a number of volts, or a digital number representation in an MCU), and convert current to a voltage or a digital representation.

b) add the signals